# How to send an email in vb6 using SMTP server

Tags: email, vb6, smtp

How to send an email to vb6 using SMTP server, I tried the below code
    but I am getting an error like this 
    run-time error'-2147220973(80040213)': the transport failed to connect 
     the server.

```
Dim x 
Public Msg 
Public IMsg As New CDO.Message Public IConf As New CDO.Configuration  
Private Sub Command1_Click() 
x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 
'lstResults.DataSource = GetMenuItems 

IConf.Fields.Item(x & "sendusing") = 2 
IConf.Fields.Item(x & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com" 
IConf.Fields.Item(x & "smtpserverport") = 465 
IConf.Fields.Item(x & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 
IConf.Fields.Item(x & "sendusername") = "parmalattest2017@gmail.com" 
IConf.Fields.Item(x & "sendpassword") = "Admin@123456" 
IConf.Fields.Item(x & "smtppusess1") = 1 
IConf.Fields.Update IMsg.To = "mohanraj.p@twilightsoftwares.com" 

IMsg.From = "parmalattest2017@gmail.com" 
IMsg.Subject = "Q & Q Statements" 
IMsg.Sender = "parmalattest2017@gmail.com" Set 
IMsg.Configuration = IConf 
IMsg.Send 

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Have you configured your GMail account to allow this.  You have to go to GMail Options and enable POP3 access. Then I think you have to click a link in an email.

Comment: Have you searched on this site (or Google) for your error message "the transport failed to connect the server"? Things come up instantly. See if one of those is the same as your problem (before entering a new question ideally).